# MySQL solution for grouped images?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

i am looking for someone who can help me to achieve a way to store multiple images as a group in mysql.

Basically a user will upload multiple images for example 3 as a group (1 POST), how can i store them in the database.

This is how i store images right now.

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| userid      | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| uploaded_at | datetime         | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| path        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| is_grouped  | int(11)          | YES  |     | 0                 |                |
| grouped_to  | int(11)          | YES  |     | 0                 |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

'is_grouped' ( 0 or 1 ) & 'grouped_to' ( id of main image ) are what i though could work but caused problems while retrieving from mysql database.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can user attach images only to posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exact problem you are having with your current approach, but I would suggest just using the following definition for the `images` table:

```
images (id, user_id, uploaded_at, path)
```

Then, create a junction table which relates images to their groups:

```
image_groups (image_id, group_id)
```

We don't really need the `is_grouped` column any more, because we can simply check `image_groups` to see if the image appears in a group and/or if that group has more than one image.  Similarly, the `grouped_to` column has now been made redundant because the junction table stores this information.  Note that you might also want to have a `groups` table, which could store some metadata about each image group, such as the name, time of creation, etc.